# color change in constants not recognized in code

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I've a folder structure like this:

[image]

Notice the `constants.swift` file I have at the top. That file contains some constants I created. One of them is:

```
let myDarkBlue = UIColor(red: 0.0/255, 
                         green: 73.0/255, 
                         blue: 120.0/255, 
                         alpha: 0.85).CGColor
```

When this was set up it worked fine and the final project still shows the original colors I had, but I changed the colors in the constant.swift file and that change is somehow not being recognized by the controllers.

The controllers are told to use myDarkBlue which originally they were but since making the color change nothing's actually changed when I run it.

Strange, right? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You either have a local variable with the same name, or you have overwritten the color in the global variable somewhere else.

One way to troubleshoot this is to to do a full project text search of `UIColor(`, I think you should then find the offending line.

Also, it is possible that you set the color in an *Interface Builder* file (such as a `.storyboard`). Depending on when exactly you set the UI elements to the specific color, it might not get changed as expected. (The controller's `viewWillAppear` is a good place.)

Comment: I did as you suggested but it didn't turn up any problems. I would add an image if I could but don't know how to add those to the comment lines.